# Reliable way of getting the max value of a column for each unique user id while meeting other criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bulk

I'm trying to bulk-get all of the latest payments for a group of user ids, but I've been struggling with getting all of them under a unified query

I went with:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM movements t1 LEFT JOIN movements t2
ON (t1.user = t2.user AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
AND t1.user IN ({$ids}) AND t1.type='payment' AND t1.concept!='4' AND t1.confirmed
```

...which worked to an extent, but some entries were being left out. I extended it to

```sql
ON (t1.user = t2.user AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t2.date IS NULL
```

and that yielded more results, but some of them weren't being selected still.

Here are two samples where the query will not yield anything

```
id      user    concept             date                    type        confirmed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29755   107     3                   2022-06-12 00:01:00     payment     1
31257   107     3                   2022-07-12 00:00:00     payment     1
32189   107     3                   2022-08-12 00:00:00     payment     1         
32460   107     COMISSION BALANCE   2022-08-23 10:50:50     comission   

id      user    concept             date                    type        confirmed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
27298   8408    3                   2022-03-11 08:44:53 40  payment     
28446   8408    3                   2022-03-11 00:01:00 40  payment     1         
28447   8408    3                   2022-04-19 17:22:42 40  payment
```

Using the "crude" alternative does, obviously.

```
SELECT * FROM movements WHERE user=107 AND (etc) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

id      user    concept             date                    type        confirmed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
32189   107     3                   2022-08-12 00:00:00     payment     1
```

Since I have the ids, I could simply do a `foreach` for every `$user` and make a million individual calls, but I'd rather avoid that.

I can tell there's something off with the "topmost" rows not meeting the full criteria, but I have no clue on how to tell SQL to get me the ones that do.

How could I achieve this in a clean way?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: so you are saying you want to select the row with the highest id for each user that matches the additional criteria, even if there's a row with a higher id that doesn't match the additional criteria?  to do that, change your where to `t1.type='payment' AND t1.concept!='4' AND t1.confirmed` and add to your on clause `and t2.type='payment' AND t2.concept!='4' AND t2.confirmed`

Comment: it would help to see the actual sql you tried; what you show should give an error that type, concept, and confirmed are ambiguous (could mean either t1 or t2).

Comment: @ysth Yeah, that's a typo on my end. I've updated the post, I was using `t1.` on the `WHERE` clause.

I was slowly arriving at this conclusion but it hadn't fully clicked yet. This was the way. 

If you turn it into an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the row with the highest id for each user that matches the additional criteria, even if there's a row with a higher id that doesn't match the additional criteria, you need to add to your on clause:

```
and t2.type='payment' AND t2.concept!='4' AND t2.confirmed
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the following:

```
Select T.id, T.user, T.concept, T.date, T.type, T.confirmed 
From
movements T 
Join 
(
  Select MAX(id) lastid, user
  From movements
  Where user IN (107, 8408) And type='payment' And concept!='4' And confirmed
  Group By user
) D
On T.id = D.lastid
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/re6uOoK4).

Comment: I prefer the solution by @ysth since it was an extension of what I was doing, but this is helpful too. I had tried the `MAX(id)` route but wasn't getting it right. Now I see I was missing the `ON` bit of the join. Definitely useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
      ,user 
      ,concept  
      ,date 
      ,type 
      ,confirmed
from  (
       select *
              ,row_number() over(partition by user order by id desc) as rn
       from   t
       where  confirmed = 1
       ) t
where  rn = 1
```

| id | user | concept | date | type | confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32189 | 107 | 3 | 2022-08-12 00:00:00 | payment | 1 |
| 28446 | 8408 | 3 | 2022-03-11 00:01:00 40 | payment | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b1s5qmVu?hide=4)